# Chebyshev-like polynomials

Tags: polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials

In some approximation problems I'm working on, the errors turned out to be polynomials of various degrees whose graphs on the interval $[-1,1]$ look like this:
[image]

As you can see, these things look a bit like Chebyshev polynomials. The one shown has degree 6. The degree $n$ polynomial in this family has the following defining properties:

- Double zeros at $t=-1$ and $t=1$
- The other $n-4$ zeros lie in $[-1,1]$
- There are $n-3$ extrema with values alternating between $-1$ and $+1$.

My questions: has this family of polynomials been studied before. If so, do they have a name, or can you provide references.

Comment: the properties seem kind of arbitrary, but you can easily give a general  formula for these polynomials, I'm not sure that giving them a name will give you more relevant information.

Comment: Thanks. Can you write the general formula in an answer, please. I'm especially interested to know the zeros

Comment: I guess $(1-\zeta^2)^2P_{n-4}^{(\alpha,\beta)}(\zeta)$ works with $P_{n}^{(\alpha,\beta)}$ normalized Jacobi Polynomials. For symmetrical Polynomials you can take Gegenbauer's.

Comment: Please define "these polynomials,".

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev. I mean the family of polynomials whose degree $n$ member is defined by the three bullet item statements. I think these statements fully define the polynomial of degree $n$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JorgeZuniga. Thanks. The answer is clearly $(1-t^2)^2$ times some polynomial $P$ of degree $n-4$. It's not obvious to me that using the Jacobi polynomials will give me the alternating extrema property. Could you elucidate, please.

Comment: Use Rodrigues' formula to show that the zeroes of $(1-\zeta^2)P_{n+1}^{(1,1)}(\zeta)$ are the locations of extrema of $(1-\zeta^2)^2P_{n}^{(2,2)}(\zeta)$. If you sort them these extremes alternate in sign. This is easily proved since 2nd derivatives $\frac{d^2}{d\zeta^2} (1-\zeta^2)^2P_{n}^{(2,2)}(\zeta)$ are proportional to Legendre Polynomials $L_{n+2}(\zeta)$ and signs interlace at these points.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga, the extremes alternate in sign but they don't have equal absolute values.

Comment: @peter_taylor. Yes, you are right, I didn't realize that. Sorry. Equally valued extrema is a strong constraint to get an inductive process to build such polynomials. I will take a look deeper trough a variation of Remez Algorithm.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga. I can compute these polynomials numerically, by using the Remez algorithm or some other approach. My question is whether any underlying theory exists. These polynomials show up immediately in certain types of approximation problems, so I expect other people have encountered them in the past. I’d like to stand on the shoulders of giants, if possible.

Comment: I can’t add an answer, since the question has been closed. However, I discovered that these things are known as “constrained Chebyshev polynomials”. They were first studied by Lachance, Varga and Saff. They are used extensively to reduce the degrees of Bézier curves and surfaces.